# Ansible - Install package pinned to major versions

Tags: ansible, package

Actual package name in the repo is `package-2.6.12-3.el7.x86_64`.

The goal is to install a package with Ansible, to:

- Ensure the point release is installed, such as package-2.6
- Doesn't install major releases, such as package-3.0
- Updates for minor releases, such as package-2.6.13-4

The repo can update packages from time to time, but I don't know when.

My thought was to install a package like this;

```yaml
- name: Install package
  yum:
    name: package-2.6
    state: present
```

But the task fails, because `package-2.6` is not in the repo. Whereas simply `package` works, but it is not future proof.

---

Update:

Seems wildcards `*` do work, eg `name: "package-2.6*"`. Ensure to quote the wildcard.

Comment: Try to use package name with full version like this: "name: package-2.6.12-3.el7.x86_64"

Comment: @YuriyZhigulskiy It's written clearly that OP does not want to specify minor version.

Comment: You want some kind of version range. I don't think that exists.

Comment: You mention wildcards work, has this solved your problem? If so please accept an answer, otherwise update with further info and we can try to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: How do I accept an answer

Comment: Bear in mind that this won't prevent 'yum update' from updating this to latest. 'yum versionlock' may be of interest, as well as disabling non-base repositories so that you get base OS updates running through, but you retain more control over application updates and testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if applicable for your Yum package. But for Java Open JDK installations where both java-1.7.0 and java-1.8.0 packages are available for installation from my configured yum repos.

This will ensure the 1.7.x version is at the latest version, without ever installing 1.8.x.

```
- name: Install latest 1.7.x jdk
  yum:
    name: java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
    state: latest
```

Actual version installed from the above is:

```
$ rpm -q java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
  java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.121-2.6.8.1.el6_8.x86_64
```

In the case of MongoDB the package name is the same for the 2.x version and the 3.x version.

But there is one Yum repo file for the 2.x version and another for the 3.x version. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

So to ensure you get the latest 2.x version without ever moving to 3.x add the 2.x repo file to your target hosts and use the `disable` and `enablerepo` parameters in your ansible task for the install/update operation.

```
 - name: Ensure latest 2.x mongodb version is installed
   yum:
     name: mongodb-org
     disablerepo: "*"
     enablerepo: mongodb-org-2.6
     state: latest
```

Note: using `disablerepo: "*"` as mongodb packages also exist in other repos such as epel.

Answer (score 8):

**Short Generic Answer:**

You should be able to just use wildcards `*`.

So just:

```
- name: Install package
  yum:
    name: package-2.6*
    state: latest
```

**Long Case Specific Answer:**

I created a test server in AWS for your specific case and found that wildcards do indeed work (EC2 instance running CentOS 7, installing `mongodb-org-server-3.4.0*).

You do need to make sure you have properly configured the mongo repository first, but you said in the comments that you are able to download the package if you provide the full version number, which is unusual. Anyway, this is the minimal playbook I made and ran:

`play.yml:`

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: centos
  tasks:
    - name: Add MongoDB repo for CentOS
      become: true
      copy:
        src: ./files/mongodb-org-3.4.repo
        dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.4.repo
    - name: Install mongodb
      become: true
      yum:
        name: mongodb-org-server-3.4.0*
        state: latest # Works with 'present' too, but won't update versions
```

This playbook copies a local file for the repo config which looks like this (path is relative to the `play.yml` file):

`files/mongod-org-3.4.repo:`

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
```

Comment: Does it just give the same error (package not found) or something else? The apt package passes wildcards through but used to have a bug where it didn't, so perhaps something similar is happening here for yum.

Comment: Package not found indeed.

Comment: Hmm, okie doke. I'll fire up a CentOS box when I get home and see if I can get something working. Am I correct in thinking the actual package you want to install is `mongodb-2.6.12-3.el7.x86_64`? What OS and version are you using on the node?

Comment: Yes, the desired package is for mongo. But this is just a simple use case.Using CentOS 7.1, ansible 2.1.2.0. Thx :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. In the meantime, have you tried installing that specific package version as a test to ensure that it is available on your system? I'm not suggesting it as a solution, but it's definitely good to rule that out.

Comment: Yes. Specific version works, eg mongodb-org-server-3.4.0-1.el7.x86_64

Comment: Hey, tested my approach above and added more info. If you have any problems with this, could you post the details for the specific packages that cause them, the error output and the relevant tasks from your ansible code? It would help debugging as then it's likely something specific to your setup.

Comment: Please add quotes due to the use of a wildcard.

Comment: Although its unlikely to be an issue with the likes of 2.6*, beware of unintended matches. 7.1* would also match 7.10, 7.11, etc. Better to include the '.'  (unless there is a version that is exactly 2.6 .... you can find out using a command such as (in my case I'm looking at versions of Kibana) `yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=elastic list --show-duplicates kibana`

Comment: Another thing to bear in mind is that even if you fully-specify a version of a package, that doesn't fully-specify its chain of dependencies. You might, therefore, end up with the situation whereby production has slightly different versions of its dependencies.